# Distorted Google Maps layer in pdf export from QGIS 2.0.1

Tags: qgis, printing, qgis-openlayers-plugin

Export of a map from QGIS 2.0.1 Composer to pdf results in distortion (changed scale) of Google map layer. Why?

Comment: Have you tried a different export format? I've found that the majority of the available open layers don't work with a Pdf. Depending on the complexity of the overlays you could try exporting as a png then saving the result as a pdf by inserting the image.